# Predual of a subspace

Tags: banach-spaces, duality, preduals

Let $E$ be a Banach space, let $d\ge 1$ be an integer. Let $\mathcal G$ be a weakly closed subspace of
$(E^*)^d$ with finite codimension.
I would like know if the  space $\mathcal G$ is a dual space $\mathcal E^*$
and if there is a somewhat explicit and canonical description of $\mathcal E.$

Comment: By "weakly closed" do you mean "weak-star closed"?

Comment: Because if you mean weak-star closed then the answer is yes (without any assumption on codimension). On the other hand, norm closed subspaces are weakly closed.

Comment: Yes, I mean weak-star closed.

Answer (score 5):

Recall the canonical isometric isomorphism  $ (X/N )^*\sim N^\perp$,  for   a Banach space $X$, and  a closed linear subspace $N$ of $X $. Also, a  linear subspace $G$ of  $X^*$ is weakly-star closed if and only if $G=(G_\perp)^\perp$.
So in the latter case $ G\sim (X/G_\perp )^*$.